# get KW in campaigns with campaign label

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to know if there is any way to get KW from campaigns that have specific campaign label

For example:
To get top 10 KW in campaigns that have campaign label that called "abc" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best method for this is to attach the campaign name as a label on the keyword level.  If you have only a few campaigns, you can go into each campaign, then keywords view within the UI, select all and add a new label with the campaign's name.

If you have a giant account (this won't work if you already have other keyword level labels set, if you do, use the first method):

1. Go to Keywords view from within the UI.Download Keywords report (check editable)
2. Then copy the contents of the C column and paste the contents into    the Label column (making sure the column is still called "Labels" [don't change anything else]
3. Then click the Reports and Uploads tab in the left navigation window.
4. Select the Uploads subtab.
5. Click "Browse for file" to locate your edited and saved report.
6. Click the "Upload" button.
7. A yellow box will appear reminding you that uploading the report will immediately update your account. (Beyond this point, there is no "undo" or "cancel" option.) Clicking "Yes, I understand" will immediately begin the process of applying your changes to your account.
8. Now all of your keywords are labeled with your campaign names!